# Using reflection, get the parent class/field of an object

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Is it possible in Java to get the 'parent' class of an object using an instance of it and its class type?

Lets say we have these two class types and the annotation type:

```
public class Foo{

}

public class Bar{

    @TestAnnotation
    public Foo mFoo = new Foo();
}

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation{

}
```

I would want to get the `Field` object of `mFoo` using an instance of `Foo`, otherwise `null`, with this I would get the annotation using `TestAnnotation test = field.TestAnnotation(SQLiteID.class);`

---

The end result I want is to know whether the instance of `Foo` is part of another type that contains a certain annotation

This seems rather far fetched so I don't expect it to be possible.

Comment: Are you asking about trying to find out if some class with a certain annotation holds a reference to the instance in `mFoo`?

Comment: Correct, my understanding of Java says that it isn't possible in a feasible way, however I wondered if there was anyone out there that new something I didn't about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible/feasible in general.

The *same object instance* can have *many names* - that is, the *same object* can be assigned to *many different* static fields, instance fields, parameters, local variables (etc) simultaneously.

All "solutions" involve some form of iteration over all such variables, which is rarely feasible and such general designs should be avoided. Even with a reduced domain (such as with annotations) a similar issue remains - i.e. how to find *all* such roots (objects instances with members having a certain annotation) of said domain?

Comment: Agreed, more of a discussion question.

Answer (score 2):

> I would want to get the Field object of mFoo using an instance of Foo.

This is doing things backwards and not possible.

You can get the `Field` of `Bar` by testing its type and then try to retrieve a specific annotation

```
Field[] fields = Bar.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
        TestAnnotation testAnnotation = field.getAnnotation(TestAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println(testAnnotation); // might be null, if annotation doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Now if you have an instance of `Foo` you can also compare it to the field value of an instance of `Bar`.

Comment: I was thinking of passing the `Bar` object to `Foo` but I don't believe it would be in any way feasible

Comment: @SmartLemon What do you mean _passing the Bar object to Foo_?

Comment: As in, if it was the parent while constructing the object Foo I could pass the instance of Bar that I am using Foo with.

Comment: @SmartLemon :( I don't understand. What parent?

Comment: No need to worry. Think of in Android passing the context to something like a `DbHelper` where it uses that context to resolve things like what applications data folder the database should be stored in.

Comment: In this context I would pass it to get that go through the fields looking for that object and get the annotations of it. But I found another way of doing it that doesn't involve anything like this :). My problem was rather unique I guess

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible *in* Java. It would be possible by [writing a JVM agent](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jvm-ti-141370.html) but would probably have a severe performance penalty because of all the bookkeeping.